# Grub "Boot from previously booted" setting not working

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 21.04

I am currently running Ubuntu 21.10 and Windows 10.  I always set up my grub the way I want using the grub-customizer tool.  Among other changes (which all worked), I set it up so that it boots from the last booted partition.  This setting worked in 20.04, but now it does not.  Instead, it always tries to boot in to Windows.

EDIT:  Here is the contents of /etc/default/grub:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=920a469a-eee8-4841-b43a-e96694ac485b"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

EDIT 2:  Here are the contents of the file within /etc/default/grub.d:  init-select.cfg

```
# Work around a bug in the obsolete init-select package which broke
# grub-mkconfig when init-select was removed but not purged.  This file does
# nothing and will be removed in a later release. 
#
# See:
#   https://bugs.debian.org/858528
#   https://bugs.debian.org/863801
```

EDIT 3:  This is the contents of /etc/grub.d:

```
./44_memtest86+
./.script_sources.txt
./43_linux_xen
./41_linux_proxy
./45_os-prober
./47_custom_proxy
./00_header
./46_uefi-firmware
./10_linux_proxy
./bin
./bin/grubcfg_proxy
./proxifiedScripts
./proxifiedScripts/custom
./proxifiedScripts/linux
./42_linux_zfs
./README
./05_debian_theme
./40_custom_proxy
./48_custom
./backup
./backup/default_grub
./backup/boot_grub
./backup/boot_grub/unicode.pf2
./backup/boot_grub/grubenv
./backup/boot_grub/grub.cfg
./backup/boot_grub/gfxblacklist.txt
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/newc.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/part_sun.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/mul_test.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/boot.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/linux.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/usb_keyboard.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/scsi.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/search_fs_file.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/pbkdf2.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/div.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/video.lst
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/part_acorn.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/nilfs2.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/usbtest.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/f2fs.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/pbkdf2_test.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/blocklist.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/datetime.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/shift_test.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/mmap.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/chain.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/core.efi
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/macho.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/cbmemc.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/ext2.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/xnu_uuid.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/part_gpt.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/morse.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/fat.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/dm_nv.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/minix_be.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/part_amiga.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/setpci.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/datehook.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/ehci.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/part_plan.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/part_apple.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/ahci.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/bsd.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/cmp.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/cpio.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/luks.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/video_cirrus.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/reboot.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/smbios.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/ls.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/random.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/hexdump.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/video_colors.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/keylayouts.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/bufio.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/nativedisk.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/usbserial_usbdebug.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/modinfo.sh
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/affs.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/reiserfs.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/lsefimmap.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/verifiers.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/video_bochs.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/videotest_checksum.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/usbms.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/date.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/mdraid09.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/trig.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/normal.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/xnu.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/pgp.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/ufs1.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/xfs.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/cs5536.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_rsa.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/parttool.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_sha512.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/raid5rec.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/zfs.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_md5.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/priority_queue.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/multiboot.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/font.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/test.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/diskfilter.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/bitmap_scale.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/backtrace.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/raid6rec.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/fshelp.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/true.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/test_blockarg.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/odc.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/ohci.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/mpi.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/hfsplus.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/efifwsetup.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/procfs.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/cbls.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/testload.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/ctz_test.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/wrmsr.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/fixvideo.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/iso9660.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_des.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/multiboot2.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/crc64.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/exfat.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/tr.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/lspci.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/memrw.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/part_bsd.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/signature_test.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/ufs2.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/ntfscomp.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/load.cfg
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/at_keyboard.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/msdospart.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_rfc2268.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/hfs.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/video_fb.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/bswap_test.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/zfscrypt.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/ata.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/relocator.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/progress.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gettext.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/cryptodisk.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/halt.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_crc.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/tpm.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/linux16.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/parttool.lst
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_md4.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/search_fs_uuid.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/cbtable.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_twofish.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/jfs.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/elf.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/lzopio.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/bitmap.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/png.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/bfs.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/geli.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/usbserial_ftdi.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/cpuid.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/div_test.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_dsa.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/efinet.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/legacycfg.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/efi_uga.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/ufs1_be.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/macbless.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/aout.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/cbfs.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_rmd160.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/tar.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/cbtime.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/terminal.lst
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/hfspluscomp.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/rdmsr.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_tiger.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/offsetio.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/usbserial_pl2303.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/syslinuxcfg.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/crypto.lst
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/loadenv.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/mdraid1x.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/lvm.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/usb.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/pata.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/romfs.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/minicmd.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gfxterm_background.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/eval.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/loopback.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/play.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/probe.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/setjmp_test.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/zfsinfo.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/lsmmap.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/partmap.lst
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_arcfour.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/keystatus.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/minix.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/cmdline_cat_test.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/part_dfly.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/hello.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_serpent.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/lsefi.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/search_label.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/btrfs.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/shim_lock.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_rijndael.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/uhci.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/hdparm.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/part_msdos.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/terminal.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/ldm.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/xzio.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/read.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/loadbios.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/iorw.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_blowfish.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_whirlpool.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/memdisk.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/sfs.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gzio.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/udf.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_sha256.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/terminfo.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/sleep.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/jpeg.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/serial.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/cat.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/all_video.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/efi_gop.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/testspeed.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/crypto.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/lsacpi.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/xnu_uuid_test.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/videotest.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/configfile.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/spkmodem.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_camellia.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/password.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/disk.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/minix3.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_seed.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_sha1.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/time.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gfxterm_menu.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/file.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/echo.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/regexp.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/search.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/minix2.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/net.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/moddep.lst
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/tga.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/tftp.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/squash4.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/lsefisystab.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/mdraid09_be.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/ntfs.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/hashsum.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/lssal.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/videoinfo.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/part_dvh.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/linuxefi.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/usbserial_common.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/help.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gptsync.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/zstd.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_idea.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/functional_test.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/adler32.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/minix2_be.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/part_sunpc.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/cmp_test.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gfxmenu.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/acpi.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/setjmp.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/password_pbkdf2.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/grub.efi
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/sleep_test.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/strtoull_test.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/appleldr.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/exfctest.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/fs.lst
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/http.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_cast5.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/video.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/gfxterm.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/legacy_password_test.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/afs.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/extcmd.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/cpio_be.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/minix3_be.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/command.lst
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/archelp.mod
./backup/boot_grub/x86_64-efi/pcidump.mod
./backup/boot_grub/fonts
./backup/boot_grub/fonts/unicode.pf2
./backup/etc_grub_d
./backup/etc_grub_d/20_linux_xen
./backup/etc_grub_d/40_custom
./backup/etc_grub_d/41_custom
./backup/etc_grub_d/30_os-prober
./backup/etc_grub_d/00_header
./backup/etc_grub_d/10_linux_zfs
./backup/etc_grub_d/30_uefi-firmware
./backup/etc_grub_d/README
./backup/etc_grub_d/20_memtest86+
./backup/etc_grub_d/05_debian_theme
./backup/etc_grub_d/10_linux
 ./backup/RESTORE_INSTRUCTIONS
```

Comment: Please see my answer. If it helps solve your problem, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grub Customizer... oh no... that usually makes a mess of things.

Anyway, edit /etc/default/grub and make sure the following lines are there...

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved    # edit existing line
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true # add this line
```

then `sudo update-grub`.

**Update #1:**

Rename your /etc/grub.dOld back to /etc/grub.d. That's why you were getting errors.

Here are the directory contents of /etc/grub.d on a 21.04 system. Should be pretty standard. Notice all of the mod dates are the same. On your system, different mod dates would indicate that something/somebody changed them. GRUB Customizer seems to have a backup/restore feature which **might** be helpful... maybe not.

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 10627 Mar 30  2021 00_header*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  6258 Mar 30  2021 05_debian_theme*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 18151 Mar 30  2021 10_linux*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 43031 Mar 30  2021 10_linux_zfs*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 12894 Mar 30  2021 20_linux_xen*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 12059 Mar 30  2021 30_os-prober*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1424 Mar 30  2021 30_uefi-firmware*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   214 Mar 30  2021 40_custom*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   216 Mar 30  2021 41_custom*
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   483 Mar 30  2021 README
```

**Update #2:**

Well, I had a right to be concerned about Grub Customizer, it really messed up things.

There's a file in /etc/grub.d/backup/RESTORE_INSTRUCTIONS which details how to uninstall the changes made by GC.

OP manually unspooled some of the changes to get the machine to boot as desired.

Comment: These lines exist in the file you told me to go to.  Except they had quotes around them (if that matters).  I tried removing the quotes and it still tried to boot me in to Windows.  I've never had problems with grub-customizer before and I don't think this is an example of it failing (as it added the lines).

Comment: @Zarquan  Did you remove the quotes and do `sudo update-grub` and then reboot? At the GRUB menu, did you select another OS to boot, and then does it remember that choice next reboot?

Comment: I did sudo update-grub after I changed the file.  But that is a good point that I didn't restart my machine twice.  I just tried and it still tries to boot to Windows.

Comment: I added the contents of my /etc/default/grub in case you can see anything wrong with it.

Comment: Normally the two lines are together, near the top of the file, but it really doesn't matter. Did you try rebooting to see if it remembered your last OS choice?

Comment: Yes.  It still tries to boot me in to Windows.

Comment: I'd say it's probably a problem with GRUB Customizer. You'd have to uninstall it, and remove all of the clutter it added to /etc/grub.d, and redo `sudo update-grub` to see if it worked then. As I mentioned earlier, GC can cause some problems.

Comment: There is nothing in /etc/default/grub.d except a file with everything commented out.  I added it to my question.  EDIT:  Oh, /etc/grub.d.  I will take a look at that.

Comment: I uninstalled grub-customizer and renamed /etc/grub.d to /etc/grub.dOld.  I ran sudo upgate-grub It is now telling me that there are syntax errors in the generated grub config file.  I tried moving the command to the top (in case of insanity) and tried with and without quotes.  I replaced grub.d just to be safe and ran grub-update.

Comment: What clutter would grub-customizer have created?  I don't know what is supposed to be there.

Comment: It just occurred to me that at some point, I may have added the UUID for the swap space so that I could hibernate my computer.  Hibernate works properly, but perhaps I messed something else up by doing that.  I'm not sure where to look to see if that could have caused the problem.

Comment: I added the contents of /etc/grub.d to my question in case you can point out where problems could be.

Comment: @Zarquan  Yes, as you can see, GC really made a mess of things, as I referred to earlier. See Update #1 in my answer for possible help.

Comment: @Zarquan Adding the UUID shouldn't have caused a problem, as long as you added the correct UUID.

Comment: @Zarquan Status please...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about this thread.  I don't see a complete reset from grub-customizer, and I didn't want to mess up my bootloader trying to reset it manually.  I managed to solve the problem by messing around with grub-customizer. It was either (1) adding a new Ubuntu boot command identical to the first one in to the boot loader OR (2) something else I tried which I can't remember. Then turning the setting off then on.  I know I tried turning the setting off and on before, so I'm still confused.  But it works now.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Zarquan  Check the ./backup/RESTORE_INSTRUCTIONS file.

Comment: I see some instructions that I could use, but I don't see a reason to do it right now because everything seems to be working.  My theory is that some setting got stuck in grub-customizer and something I did got it to check a value it assumed to be set in a certain way.

Comment: If you alter your answer to talk about resetting GRUB using the RESTORE_INSTRUCTIONS file, I will mark it as an answer, as being able to easily reset my grub would certainly have solved my problem.

Comment: @Zarquan Edits made. Thanks!